# Scattering a contiguous 2D Array using MPI

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, mpi

I don't seem to get this right, i want to scatter a 2D block and just print the scattered parts, this is for testing purpose
Here's what I'm trying to do ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi/mpi.h"

void print2D(int**, int, int);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int rank, pSize, r1, c1, rowsPerProcess, i, j;
    int** matA = NULL, **partMat = NULL;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pSize);

    if(rank == 0)
    {
    scanf("%d%d", &r1, &c1);
        rowsPerProcess = r1/pSize; // number of rows assigned to each process (Assume this produces no remainder)

    //Contiguous allocation
        int* mat1D = (int*)malloc(r1 * c1 * sizeof(int));
        matA = (int**)malloc(r1 * sizeof(int*));
        for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
          matA[i] = &mat1D[i * c1];

    for(i=0; i<r1; i++) //Fill the 2D array
      for(j=0; j<c1; j++)
        matA[i][j] = i + j;

    printf("Original Matrix:\n");
    print2D(matA, r1, c1);
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&c1, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //Columns
    MPI_Bcast(&rowsPerProcess, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //Rows in every process

    //Again, contiguous allocation for the partial 2D array
    int* partMat1D = (int*)malloc(rowsPerProcess * c1 * sizeof(int));
    partMat = (int**)malloc(rowsPerProcess * sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<rowsPerProcess; i++)
          partMat[i] = &partMat1D[i * c1];

    MPI_Scatter(&(matA[0][0]), rowsPerProcess * c1, MPI_INT, &(partMat[0][0]),
    rowsPerProcess * c1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("FROM PROCESS %d:\n", rank);
    print2D(partMat, rowsPerProcess, c1);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

void print2D(int** mat, int row, int col)
{
    if(mat != NULL)
    {
        int i, j;
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<col; j++)
                printf("%d  ", mat[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

and I receive a segmentation fault error on running this with 4 processes
e.g.

```
8 3
Original Matrix:
0  1  2  
1  2  3  
2  3  4  
3  4  5  
4  5  6  
5  6  7  
6  7  8  
7  8  9  
FROM PROCESS 0:
0  1  2  
1  2  3  

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 2637 RUNNING AT minix-VirtualBox
=   EXIT CODE: 139
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

Only process 0 print its part correctly.
Am i using MPI_Scatter wrong? how do i fix this?
how do i scatter this 2D block right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the non-master processes, you initialize `matA` to `NULL`, and then proceed to evaluate the expression `&matA[0][0]`. This dereferences `matA`, crashing your process even before it enters `MPI_Scatter()`.

---

Since you are programming in C, you can avoid those double pointers: C has quite good multidimensional array support built in since C99, and you can use it to make your life much easier. Just declare `matA` as a pointer to a line array

```
int (*matA)[c1];
```

then allocate an array of `r1` rows for it

```
matA = malloc(r1*sizeof(*matA));
```

After that you can fill your array with the same code as you used in your code above:

```
for(i=0; i<r1; i++) //Fill the 2D array
  for(j=0; j<c1; j++)
    matA[i][j] = i + j;
```

Also, since your 2D array needs only one `malloc()` call, you can also dispose it off with a single `free()` call:

```
free(matA);
```

Note: You cannot do this in C++, it does not support variable length arrays the way C does, and probably never will. This is one of the few points where C is much more powerful than C++.

Comment: thanks for this 2d array tip! but I removed this initialization with NULL and I'm still having the same error

Comment: The problem is not the initialization with `NULL`, it is the failure to initialize with some meaningful value that can actually be dereferenced.

Comment: so what do you suggest? broadcast the entire matA matrix to all the processes before scattering?

Comment: No, definitely not. I would pass `mat1D` to `MPI_Scatter()` if I had used your allocation. But I'd rather use the C99 2D-array version and call MPI_Scatter() simply with `matA` as the first argument. In that case it would not matter if `matA` is NULL on the non-root processes because it's never dereferenced.

Comment: Oh I got it now! I made mat1D and partMat1D seen by all processes and changed the call to `MPI_Scatter(mat1D, rowsPerProcess * c1, MPI_INT, partMat1D,
    rowsPerProcess * c1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` and it worked .. I think I'll switch to the version of 2D array you suggested .. any idea how to pass `int (*matA)[c1];` to my `print2D()` function

Comment: With the 2D array approach, `matA` is still just a pointer (which happens to point at an array), so you pass it to functions as you would pass any other pointer. I. e. the function will declare its arguments as `print2D(int rowCount, int colCount, int (*matrix)[colCount])`, and it will be called as `print2D(r1, c1, matA);`. Note that the `colCount` argument needs to precede the `matrix` argument, because you need `colCount` to declare the type of `matrix`.